# How can I use my beats studio 3 headphones as both a speaker and a microphone on a custom built PC

Tags: audio, headphones

I used to have a MacBook Pro from 2013, and on that laptop, I could plug in my headphones and they would work both as a speaker and a microphone without any issues. I could use Discord with only the headphones!

When I plug my headphones into my PC, they only act as speakers. Discord does not recognize my headphones, even after going into voice and video settings in Discord and trying to select an audio device. If I select 'Default' it does not work. An image is attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AFtt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

After searching around online, I was able to find this solution: https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/369296/how-to-use-a-mobile-headset-microphone-with-a-desktop-pc/amp/

Essentially, you have to buy a female to 2 male cable that splits the signal from your headphones in two.